# Horizontal positioning of vertical arrows between lines in an alignment

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, arrows, mathtools

I'm trying to get a construction like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
    &\Downarrow \\
  a &= c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

to look good. The problem is that the `\Downarrow` is not horizontally centered between the `=` signs. While I understand why this happens and why a `\mathrel{\Downarrow}` doesn't help, I don't know how to fix it. I'm aware of the `\ArrowBetweenLines[\Downarrow]` function in `mathtools`, but that is for having the arrow to the left of the aligned lines. I would ideally want something that works the same way `\vdotswithin{=}` does (from `mathtools`). Does that exist somewhere? Or would it be difficult to manually "create a box corersponding to `{}={}` and typeset a" `\Downarrow` "centered inside it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the definition of `\vdotswithin` from [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools):

```
\newcommand\vdotswithin[1]{%
  {\mathmakebox[\widthof{\ensuremath{{}#1{}}}][c]{{\vdots}}}}
```

You can update this to something called `\symbolwithin{<symbol>}{<within symbol>}` (say):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\symbolwithin[2]{%
  {\mathmakebox[\widthof{\ensuremath{{}#2{}}}][c]{{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
    &\symbolwithin{\Downarrow}{=} \\
  a &= c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion that exact function would have been a nice addition to `mathtools` (with a corresponding version for less vertical spacing).

Comment: I can't find `\mathmakebox{}` documented anywhere, and don't see how it behaves differently than '\makebox'. It seems to be part of `mathtools` but it's not explained in the manual. Do you know if it makes a difference here?

Comment: @tanh: `\makebox` defaults to setting its contents using `\textstyle` when using `$`..`$` for setting math, while `\mathmakebox` checks the current math mode and conditions accordingly without having to use `$`..`$`.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I put the downarrow in a box the size of an equals sign

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
    &\makebox[\widthof{${}={}$}]{$\Downarrow$} \\
  a &= c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the optional argument `[c]` is necessary. Isn't it the default?

Comment: @Bernard  Correct.  It was vestigial and I have removed it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Perfect, thank you. This kind of makes me wish `\vdotswithin{=}` were generalized to something like `\symbolwithin{\vdots}{=}` with a corresponding `\shortsymbolwithin{}{}` version for less vertical space (which I imagine is more complex).